# How to check email exists in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Hi I'm using firebase and javascript. I need to check for email id existing or not when new user signs up. This code works for user name or id, but shows error having email as record. I don't want to overwrite firebase unique key generation for each record.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://kkk.firebaseio.com/");
var users = ref.child("users");
var userId = document.getElementById("email").value;
function checking()
{
   checkIfUserExists(userId);
}  
function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
  if (exists) {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' exists!');
  } else {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' does not exist!');
    var check = users.push({ email: username});
  }
}

function checkIfUserExists(userId) {

  users.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
  });
}
```

I'm getting this error when I enter email.

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "anu@gmail.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

I want my data in firebase to looks like this,

```
users:{
       "ksjhfsjkbv67dsjhbcxcscdg":{
          "email": "sdfs@gmail.com"
       },
       "kXdhbrurjw9974jjdsos_asd":{
          "email": "anu@gmail.com"
       },
       ...
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It's not clear to me why this exists: function checking() { checkIfUserExists(userId); } Next, it isn't clear to me where you're GETTING the value for userID. I believe you mean to put checkIfUserExists(username); in there somewhere. Perhaps that's your only problem. Next most obvious question...
Does kkk.users.anu@gmail.com exist in your firebase account?

Comment: The error may be because of how the data is structured in firebase. Can you update your question with example firebase data - the /users node would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're data in firebase has unique keys then it probably looks something like:

```
{
    users:{
       "dsjhfsjkbv67dsjhbcxcscdg":{
          "email": "blah@whatever.com"
       },
       "sXdhbrurjw9974jjdsos_asd":{
          "email": "anu@gmail.com"
       },
       ...
}
```

}

the error your getting is because you cannot have illegal characters as the "keys" for your data so:

```
{
    "anu@gmail.com": "email"
}
```

would not be acceptable hence the error:

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "anu@gmail.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

the "." is not allowed.

One way to check if your value exists if you do not know the unique key is to do something like:

```
users.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = false;
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        if(userId === childSnapshot.val().email){
            exists = true;     
        }
    })
    userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
});
```

you can read more about the for each function here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html

Comment: `users.once('value'` will start hurting performance as you get more users. `users.orderByChild('email').equalTo(userId).once(...` will perform a lot better. Better still would be to store all user ids by their email address as in your second sample. Just replace the `.` with a `,` (which isn't valid in an email address, but *is* valid in a Firebase key) and you'll have the lookup list most developers use to allow each email address only once.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. But I dont want to generate a key with email. I need the randomly generated key by firebase. How could I traverse through the firebase and check for existing email.

Comment: @Anu did you ever figure out how to do this? I need this function so badly

Comment: @NickGarver which part?  The creating a user with unique firebase ID or how to check if a user exists?

Comment: @Kyle checking if a user exists. i want to display the result in a div or something so when a new account is being created they will know

Comment: Sounds like your use case may be a bit different than the OP - What your describing sounds like you might want to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword() - this will return (auth/email-already-in-use) if it already exsists which you can handle accordingly( display to the user) otherwise it will create a new account.  ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: This answer that I accepted is working fine in my case @NickGarver

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to check if the email already has an account because firebase can not create another account with the same email.